# How long can a qubit exist without decoherence?

Tags: quantum-state, decoherence

In 2020, practically speaking, how long (time-wise) will a qubit function normally before decoherence kicks in?

Comment: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kane_quantum_computer , phosphorous qubits allegedly have decoherence times on the order of 10**18 years

Comment: @MohammadAthar: It is acutally $10^{18}$ seconds but it is still very long time.

Answer (score 3):

On IBM Q, it is a few tens microseconds. The best value of dephasing time T2 is around 500 microseconds. Have a look here [IBM Q website](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/support/guides/introduction-to-quantum-circuits) and navigate to "Qubits as physical system" and then to "dephasing T2" to see development of T2 in last twenty years.

Answer (score 1):

Nuclear moments of europium ions have been [experimentally measured](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14025) to have coherence times of over six hours, although there is no currently known way of performing controlled logic gate operations on them.

Comment: I think these construction was intended for quantum RAM and future global quantum communication network.